# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext

Tags: java, kotlin

I have this error for days, it happens when I try to run the application in Android Studio. But I haven't been able to find a solution. Can you help me please?

What could be causing the problem?

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x2a7a8a85) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x2a7a8a85
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:287)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:540)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:531)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:113)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:531)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x2a7a8a85) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x2a7a8a85
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:40)
```

The problem occurs when running the project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.